# (C) Comparing two elements of a long long array after scanning won't work

Tags: c, arrays, compare, scanf

I tried to create a function in C that fills a long long array by scanning, but won't accept another scan, if the element is already there. Then it asks to overwrite the doubled element. I need to do it like this because of other conditions I need to check, so array[0] needs to stay outside and I have to use a while.

```
void fillArray(long long array[]) {

    int i = 1, j = 0, size = 1;
    scanf("%Ld", &array[0]);
    while (i < OG && array[i-1] != 0) {
        scanf("%Ld", &array[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            while (array[j] == array[i]) {
                printf("Try again!\n");
                scanf("%Ld", &array[i]);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I tried to enter `1, 2, 1`, and although it accepts `array[0]` as `1` and `array[2]` as `1`, the condition `array[j] == array[i]` is not fulfilled. I just don't get why.

Comment: I'm surprised you even got this to compile. To read a `long long int`, use `%lld`, not `%Ld`. Try turning on warnings next time you compile (`-Wall` at the command line).

Comment: The logic for testing uniqueness is broken - you need to go back to the beginning of the array whenever the user enters a new value for a duplicate entry, not just re-test the current element.

Comment: Suggest testing and handling the result of `scanf()`.  Best to simply read a line with `fgets()` and then `sscanf()` it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it will be a good idea to define a second parameter of  the function that will specify the size of the array. 
Take into account that the function should return the number of filled elements. Though if the mark of the end of the array is the element with value equal to zero then you may define the function as having return type void and return nothing.:)

I would write the function the following way

```
size_t FillArray( long long array[], size_t n ) 
{
    size_t i, j;

    if ( n == 0 ) return n;

    i = 0;

    scanf( "%Ld", &array[0] );

    while ( ++i < n && array[i-1] != 0 ) 
    {
        do
        { 
            scanf( "%Ld", &array[i] );

            j = 0;
            while  ( j < i && array[j] != array[i] ) j++;

            if ( j != i )
            {
                printf( "Try again!\n" );
            }
        } while ( j != i );
    }

    return i;
}
```

The version with return type void

```
void FillArray( long long array[], size_t n ) 
{
    size_t i, j;

    if ( n == 0 ) return;

    i = 0;

    scanf( "%Ld", &array[0] );

    while ( ++i < n && array[i-1] != 0 ) 
    {
        do
        { 
            scanf( "%Ld", &array[i] );

            j = 0;
            while  ( j < i && array[j] != array[i] ) j++;

            if ( j != i )
            {
                printf( "Try again!\n" );
            }
        } while ( j != i );
    }
}
```

However in this version of the function the size of the array shall not be equal to 0. Otherwise it will be impossible to distinguish whether the array was filled or the second parameter was equal to 0.

Also you can insert a check whether scanf ended with an error.

Comment: I'd be happier if you test the result of `scanf()`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler It is not my assignment. Let he do something himself.:)

Comment: Since his teacher hasn't drummed into him "check the return value from `scanf()`', we'll have to do it for the teacher.  Good answers show good coding style, and checking input functions is IMNSHO a crucial part of good coding style.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Well Let's wait when the teacher ask a question about the good programming style.:)

Answer (score 0):

in this part

```
while (array[j] == array[i]) {
            printf("Try again!\n");
            scanf("%Ld", &array[i]);
        }
```

I think you should use an `if` instead of a `while` because the `while` will be left when `array[0] != array[i]` and thus wont check the rest of the array for similarities

Comment: I'd be happier if you test the result of `scanf()`.